# Remove items in node.js array that start the same

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with the following values. I use this for an SQL search

```
var arr = ["ann%", "annie%", "aine%", "pat%", "annabelle%","patrick%" ]
```

I want remove values that that will be duplicated in the SQL. In this example `"annie%"` and `"annabelle%"` and `"patrick%"` results will be found with `"ann%"` and `"pat%"` searches so they are not required.

I need some node.js code that will return an array like this from the original.

```
var arr1 = ["ann%", "aine%", "pat%" ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Take a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on how to update this question to improve the chances that you get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can  use `filter()` and `some()`  with something like this -- making sure not to filter out exact matches:

```js
var arr = ["ann%", "annie%", "aine%", "pat%", "annabelle%","patrick%" ]

arr2 = arr.filter(testEl => !arr.some(item => item !== testEl && testEl.startsWith(item.replace('%',''))))
console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: This same code will work even if values in the array don't have the `%`. But if you know they won't have the `%`, you can shorten it by removing: `.replace('%','')` The test will just be `testEl.startsWith(item)`